# SwiftUI Menu breaks layout

Tags: ios, layout, swiftui, menu, truncation

This sample SwiftUI app (Xcode 12.5.1) consists of a `Menu` and a button. Tapping the button toggles the title of the menu between "Short Text" and "Much Longer Text".

Unfortunately, the layout does not perform correctly. As you can see, the "Much Longer Text" is needlessly truncated. But once the menu title is tapped and the menu briefly appears, the title grows to its proper (untruncated) size and the problem disappears:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textIsLong = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                Text("Menu Item")
            } label: {
                Text(textIsLong ? "Much Longer Text" : "Short Text")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
            .lineLimit(1)

            Button("Toggle Title", action: { textIsLong.toggle()})
        }
    }
}
```

In contrast, replacing the menu with `Text(textIsLong ? "Much Longer Text" : "Short Text")` eliminates the problem; the text is never truncated.

Is this just a SwiftUI layout bug? Either way, can you think of a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by setting the `.frame()` of the `Text` in the `Menu` label to the following to resolve the truncation and layout break

```
Menu {
    Text("Menu Item")
} label: {
    Text(textIsLong ? "Much Longer Text" : "Short Text")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  // making maxWidth infinity 
}
```

Comment: You can also probably get rid of `minWidth: 0` - `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` is usually enough

Comment: Oh yea, let me correct that real quick. Force of habit

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why your fix is necessary, according to the rules of layout? It would seem to me that it shouldn't be and that, in any case, whether or not a menu has ever been invoked should be irrelevant to the size of the menu title when the menu itself is not visible.

Comment: I'm assuming since you haven't explicitly given a frame, and since swiftUI is declarative, it tries to update the frame which causes the layout break. When you provide the frame as `.infinity` it is forced to span across to the maximum width of the screen. Hence, giving no room for frame updates.

Comment: This is a bug, really. There isn't any part of the layout or render model that makes sense here.